# Hyper-V swich, give internal network access to Internet on Win 8

Tags: hyper-v, windows-8, vswitch

I'm running a lab environment on my W8 laptop, using Hyper-V. I've set up a virtual switch that's internal, but I would prefer to give the internal machines access to the internet.

Ok, why not an external switch then? Well, for starters I only have one NIC and I move my computer between different locations (home, work, etc) so I've DHCP configured on the NIC and I don't want DHCP in the lab environment.

Is there any smart way to get internet access to the virtual network? Bridging the virtual and physical NIC doesn't seem to work any good. I've thought about running a virtual router connected to both the internal switch and an external switch (both Hyper-V virtual switches of course). But Before trying that I figured it might be an easier way?

Since the physical machine runs Win 8 there's no Routing and Remote Access feature on the machine, like it would be on a Win server box.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shame on me, I just realized that Win 8 can do exactly what I want to do, all I had to do was to share my physical NIC with my internal vNIC and now my internal virtual machines have access to the outside World.

Hopefully this might help someone else.

Comment: By 'share' do you mean bridge, via the Network Connections UI?